# Remover Título da barra de menu

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Alguém sabe me dizer como faço pra remover o Título da barra de menu? Vi alguns materiais na internet mas todos ensinam a remover a barra e eu quero remover apenas o título.

Comment: Você se refere ao `Toolbar`, a barra superior onde fica o nome do app?

Comment: Sim. Isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Ou dessa forma

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Deu certinho! Muito obrigada... salvou minha noite!

Comment: Fico feliz em lhe ajudar =)  Marque minha resposta como a correta, isso me ajuda.

Comment: Acho que marquei. Confere ai. Sou nova aqui. :)

Comment: Marcou sim, obrigado! Isso dá uma motivada. Bem-vinda! Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour